# How to change Environment Variables before tested class takes them?

Tags: jestjs, environment-variables, ts-jest

I have an application config file, that gets the environment variables from the environment. It looks like this:

```js
import { config } from "dotenv";

config({path: ".env"});
config({path: ".env.local"});

export default class ApplicationConstants {
  public static DatabaseHost = process.env.DB_HOST;
  public static DatabasePort = +process.env.DB_PORT;
  public static DatabaseName = process.env.DB_NAME;
  public static DatabaseUsername = process.env.DB_USER;
  public static DatabasePassword = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;
}
```

I have a `.env` file that looks like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=postgres
DB_NAME=someapp
```

And I have a `.env.local` file that looks like this:

```
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

My test looks like this:

```js
import ApplicationConstants from "../../config/application-constants";

describe("ApplicationConstants", () => {
  const applicationConstants = ApplicationConstants;
  const expectedConfig = {
    DB_HOST: "someHost",
    DB_PORT: "1234",
    DB_NAME: "someName",
    DB_USER: "someUser",
    DB_PASSWORD: "somePassword",
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .clearAllMocks()
      .resetAllMocks()
    process.env = {...expectedConfig};
  });

  test("DatabaseHost", () => {
    const result = applicationConstants.DatabaseHost;

    expect(result).toEqual(expectedConfig.DB_HOST);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, `process.env.DB_HOST` is `localhost` instead of `someHost`.

How can I get the test to use the values from the `process.env` object that I set in the `beforeEach` block?

**Note:**
I don't want to test my env variables. I want to test if the ApplicationConfig takes them right (prevent change of names, ...)